# print a character horizontally using the for loop

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

I'm trying to print characters `n` numbers of times horizontally, and thus far, I have this code:

```
#print n times  *

times=input("¿How many times will it print * ? " )

for i in range(times):
  print"* \t"
```

but the result is this:

¿How many times will it print * ? 5
*
*
*
*
*

How do I make the asterisk print horizontally?

EG:
`* * * * * *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because by default, python's `print` function adds a newline after it, you'll want to use sys.stdout.write(), as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

EG:

```
#print n times  *
import sys
times=input("¿How many times will it print * ? " )

for i in range(times):
  sys.stdout.write("* \t")
#Flush the output to ensure the output has all been written
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to cast your input into int.

Second, by adding a comma at the end of your print statement, it will print horizontal.

Also, as you are using python 2.x, you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`

```
times = int(raw_input("How many times will it print * ? " ))

for i in range(times):
  print "* \t",
```

**Output:**

```
*   *   *   *   *
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by trying this.  As far as I know, print() systematically inserts a \n (line break) after each call, so the solution is to call "print()" only once.

```
#print n times  *

times=input("¿How many times will it print * ? " )

str = ""
for i in range(times):
  str += "* \t"

print(str)
```